# rDotNet library warning in R 4.0.0

Tags: r, r.net

rDotNet library seems to have the following issue with R 4.0.0. Does someone know how to fix this?

```
> library(rDotNet)
attempting to build CLR server, one time setup
Warning message:
In fun(libname, pkgname) :
  could not find nuget in path; will not be able to use rDotNet unless corrected and rebuilt
```

Comment: what OS are you using?  I suspect you are using either osx or Linux?  If either of these, then you need to make sure you have installed dotnet and that nuget is in your path.

Comment: I am using windows 10.

Comment: If you are using osx or linux, you need to make sure that you have nuget and msbuild in the path.  Can test by running: `nuget` and see whether it is found from the command line.   

On OSX, I installed nuget by running `brew install nuget`